# unable to change text into image in php

Tags: php

Iam trying to change text to image using str_replace but its not happening.  The code which i tried is below:-

```
<?php
  $str="jason";
  $search=array("j","a","s","o","n");
  $replace=array(
    "<img src=img/j.png />",
    "<img src=img/a.png />",
    "<img src=img/s.png />",
    "<img src=img/o.png />",
    "<img src=img/n.png />"
  );
  echo str_replace($search, $replace, $str)."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: [works for me](http://codepad.org/d75aPBtj)

Comment: @Peter. It works, but not how OP wants it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) doesn't work because it performs the replacement one after the other.

You could use [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$str = "jason";

echo strtr($str, array(
    'j' => "<img src=img/j.png />",
    'a' => "<img src=img/a.png />",
    's' => "<img src=img/s.png />",
    'o' => "<img src=img/o.png />",
    'n' => "<img src=img/n.png />"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

**you should try this function as it is working 100%**

```
function test_image()
        {

    $string = 'string';
                $letters = preg_split('//', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // this gives you an array with one letter in each element
                $images = array();
                foreach($letters as $letter)
                {
                $images[] = '<img src="' . $letter . '.jpg" />';
                }
                $images_string = implode($images);
                echo $images_string;
        }
```

Comment: i think [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is easyier/faster